# External PDF viewer showing error for file compiled on TeXStudio

Tags: pdftex, texstudio

I made a file in TeXStudio and clicked 'Save As' and saved it as a .pdf file. However, when I try to open that pdf, my PDF viewer (which is Adobe Acrobat Reader), says that the file is either not of a supported type, or has been damaged. Could anyone provide a solution as to how I can fix this?

Comment: Erh, does texstudio actually give you the possibility to save a file in texstudio as a pdf? I'm pretty sure you just saved a tex file (which is pure text) as a file with the .pdf extension, that does not make the file into a pdf. Have texstudio compile the file to pdf instead. There is usually an icon with an arrow head pointing right

Comment: Thanks for the tip!